# Cannot load stores using jsonp extjs4.1

Tags: json, extjs4, jsonp

I am trying to load ext data stores using jsonp. The below code is working fine when i am using ajax and making requests on the same domain.

**The store definition:**

```
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8090/'; 

Ext.define('Ktimatologio.store.NewWholeBlockStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'widget.newsingleblockstore',

    requires: ['Ktimatologio.model.NewWholeBlockModel'],

    model: 'Ktimatologio.model.NewWholeBlockModel',

    groupField: 'search_tag',

    fields: [   
        {name:'id', mapping:'id'},
        {name:'id1', mapping:'id1'},
        {name: 'text', mapping: 'text'},
        {name: 'title', mapping: 'title'},
        {name: 'fek', mapping: 'fek'},
        {name: 'date', mapping: 'date'},
        {name: 'descr', mapping: 'description'},
        {name: 'model', mapping: 'model'},
        {name: 'body', mapping: 'body'},
        {name: 'type', mapping: 'type'},
        {name: 'history', mapping: 'history'},
        {name: 'src', mapping: 'url'},
        {name: 'search_tag', mapping: 'search_tag'},
        {name: 'new_element', mapping: 'new_element'},
        {name: 'new_table', mapping: 'new_table'}
        ],

    autoLoad: true, 

    proxy: {
        //type:'ajax',
        type:'jsonp',
        url: baseUrl + 'openbd/ktimatologio-final/resources/cfScripts/nea_stoixeia/GetNewTables.cfc?',
        extraParams: {
            method: 'getNewTables'
            },
        reader:{
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
```

When i run the code i see an error on firebug:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
{"data":[{"id":"1_n_2308_1995","id1":1,"title":"Άρθρο 1&nbspΦΕΚ Α΄ 114&nbsp15.6....

GetNew...llback2 (line 1, column 1)
```

I am stuck!

Any help is much appreciated!

Tom

Greece

Answer (score 0):

JSONP service must actually return a function call not just JSON back. Google for some examples.